# Is there a way to get Photo Booth not to flash when it takes a photo?

Tags: macos, photos, photo-booth

Is there a way to get Photo Booth not to flash when it takes a photo?

It washes out every picture I take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is Hold down **Shift** and click the **red** **button**

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the shift key while taking the photo.